# Is there a usage of "subject" as adjective meaning "mentioned"?

Tags: word-meaning

In my company, in some documents, "subject" is used in the same meaning as "mentioned".

The following is an example of how it is used in my company:

> "Subject change is applicable to them (specific automotive models)."

I looked up the meaning of "subject" as adjective but I didn't see any definition saying "subject" means "mentioned".

Can I use "subject" instead of "this" and "mentioned" in the sentences below:

> - **This** modification affects certain car models.
> - **Mentioned** modification affects certain car models.
> - **Subject** modification affects certain car models.

Or, can I use subject to refer to things that I mentioned or will mention about?

Comment: *But in my company, in some documents, "subject" is used in the same meaning as "mentioned".* Can you provide an example sentence? Better if it is a sentence actually written in your office document.

Comment: @AIQ I add an example sentence to question, which is "Subject change is applicable to them(specific automotive models).",  written in the documents.

Comment: Your first option - "This modification" - is easy to understand.  The second option is poor english; it would need to be "The modification mentioned affects certain car models".  The third option does not make much sense on its own.

Comment: @TechnoCat Can we use "subject" as attributive noun instead of "this"?

Comment: @over_twenty_five - As it stands, and with no further information, the sentence beginning with "Subject" makes no sense at all to me.  Subject modification" would normally be capable of being rephrased as "Modification of the subject".  But university courses have subjects ... not cars! It's possible that there is some missing contextual information (e.g. the preceding sentence) that helps a reader of the manual understand it, or maybe the term "subject" is used in a technical sense understood by staff of the company.  However, on its own, the answer to your question is "no".  "

Comment: @over_twenty_five, is English the native language of the writer(s)? Or, which language?  It would be helpful to post examples actually written in your office document, with surrounding context (a few sentences before and after the use of the word "subject").

Comment: @Sam No, he is not native english speaker and he said that he used “subject” in the way that it means “this” or “mentioned”. the original sentence is “Subject change is applicable to mercedes-benz E200 series”. there is no any sentences before and after the sentence in the section which it was used. Also “change” refer to whole document describing the modification.

Comment: @over_twenty_five it is surprising there are not any sentences before and after that one.   Anyway, viewing only that one sentence in isolation, it does not make a lot of sense.